# AutoHotKey: Simulate winkey+s (universal search) by pressing ctrl+space

Tags: windows-8.1, autohotkey

Ideally I'd like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to bring up "search everywhere" from anywhere in windows (8.1) and also dismiss it if it's already active (with something like #IfWinActive ...).

So far I've been able to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> simulate pressing the <kbd>winkey</kbd> with the following AutoHotKey script:

```
<^Space::
KeyWait Ctrl
Send {RWin}
return
```

...but not <kbd>winkey</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. It feels sort of hackish anyway because it doesn't initiate "on press." It only initiates once I've released the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

P.S. If I can't get this figured out I'm taking suggestions for a good third party launcher application

---

EDIT: Thanks to Robert. Here is the result:

```
<^Space::
SendInput {RWin Down}s{RWin Up}
return
```

Comment: Are you trying to send <kbd>win+s</kbd> by pushing <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd>?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry if I was unclear. I'm thinking about using a launcher like Launchy because you can specify the hotkey but not if I don't have to.

Comment: Why do you use `KeyWait Ctrl` if you want the hotkey to trigger directly?

Comment: Because I'm just kind of hacking this thing together and the script would stop working whenever I removed that line. But for some reason it is working perfectly after removing that line plus changing `Send {RWin}` to `SendInput {RWin Down}s{RWin Up}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is through:

```
 SendInput, {RWin Down}s{RWin Up}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Random comma in there but otherwise it is perfect.

Comment: @TheBlackKeys This isn't a "random" comma. Commas in AHK commands are delimiters for parameters. The comma between the command and the first parameter is optional, but can help make code cleaner. I believe it's easier to read AHK code if parameters are throughout separated by commas, so that commands can be told apart from their parameters at first glance. For instance, imagine a code line like this `Run Run.exe`... a comma would minimize the potential for confusion.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for clearing that up. I'm all about clean code.

Comment: @MCL thanks for clarifying. I had wondered about "," after commands

Comment: @TheBlackKeys In this case, consider indenting the code in hotkey labels. That is, in your hotkey, indent `SendInput` by two or three spaces. A hotkey label is technically the same as subroutines or functions.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
^Space::SendInput, #s
```